# ArcGIS for Server, find publisher of a service?

Tags: arcgis-server, services

Is there a way to find out who published an ArcGIS Server service? In ArcGIS Server manager there seems to be no way to get this information, something like 'published by...' or something?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but in the ArcServer Manager > select service > general tab > under original document > there are two properties 'Machine Name' & 'Path'... This is the machine (computer) who published and the path the source of the service.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, just thought of a more convenient way... So next Monday I'm gonna ask all my the publishers on my ArcGIS Server for their computers names and I'm done ;-)